# Smart compare function for decimal numbers with currency in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have given an array with European numbers with currency symbol at the end:

```
var array = ['2,75 €', '2,05 €', ...]
```

I am looking for a smart way to sort it numerical via

```
array.sort(<sortFunction>)
```

Comment: Convert each value to a number by removing the currency symbol, replacing `,` with `.` and passing the result to `Number`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
const array = ['2,75 €', '2,05 €', '10,0 €']

const sorted = array.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true}))

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Impressive. It is even ignoring the €

Comment: Which locale is chosen if `undefined` is passed?

Comment: Mh. I get "a.localeCompare is not a function. (In 'a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true})', 'a.localeCompare' is undefined)"? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @FelixKling Its not mentioned in [ecma standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.localecompare) :( . Here I just tried to skip the optional locale part using `undefined`

Comment: @mrbela: In which environment are you running the code?

Comment: @mrbela may be the array contains mixed type like strings and numbers. `localeCompare` works with strings. so, try `a.toString().localeCompare(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own comparator function this way: It returns a negative number if `a<b`, positive if the other way around and zero if equal. To compare both numbers, you just have to replace `,` by `.` before parsing a float value.

No need to remove the `€` when using parseFloat

```js
const array = ['2,75 €', '2,05 €', '10,0 €']
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a.replace(",", ".")) - parseFloat(b.replace(",", "."));
});

console.log(array)
```

Comment: @mplungjan Just checked this, you are right, thank you.